# Examples of hyperbolic and non-hyperbolic space for quasi-isometric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ are quasi-isometric spaces. I try to find an example for which one of these spaces will be hyperbolic, other is not hyperbolic.

I know that for geodesic metric space if one of the quasi-isometric spaces is a hyperbolic space also it's truth for second space.

It's interesting to see some examples where the hyperbolicity is not a quasi-isometric invariant.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "hyperbolicity"? There is Gromov hyperbolicity of geodesic metric spaces... but [Gromov hyperbolicity is indeed a quasi-isometry invariant among geodesic metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_metric_space#Invariance_under_quasi-isometry) so it seems clear that you must have something else in mind.

Comment: You should clarify that hyperbolicity in your post refers to Gromov's 4-point condition. It is indeed not qi invariant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes you are right. I mean hyperbolictiy in the sense of Gromov product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the "standard example:"

Let $X$ denote the real line with the standard metric. Let $Y\subset {\mathbb R}^2$ be the graph of the function $f(x)=|x|$ with the metric (the distance function) obtained by restriction of the standard metric on the plane. I will leave it to you to check that $X$ is hyperbolic, $Y$ is not (in the sense of the definition via the Gromov-product) and to construct a quasi-isometry $X\to Y$.